# How to enable and disable Appearance from WordPress Dashboard

Tags: wordpress, themes

The custom theme that I am working on now has no Appearance. It is using the Themosis Framework. Please help me to enable the Appearance if the Super Admin is logged in.

I tried to test the `add_menu_page` but no luck.

```
Action::add('admin_menu', function(){
    if (isSuperAdmin()) {
        add_menu_page('themes.php');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Already fixed it using this:

`add_menu_page('appearance', 'Appearance', 'manage_options', 'themes.php' ,'', 'dashicons-admin-appearance', 30);`